# How to get CSVWriter to add blob data into cell

Tags: android, sqlite, csv, blob, writer

I have an application that allows the user to sign the tablet and an image will be produced.  That part I have working with confirmation as I am able to view the images after they are created and saved.

I am writing them to a .csv file with the following code.

```
//region - Create CSV file
            writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(sdCardPath + "Orders_Summary_Report.csv"), ',', CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER, CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER, "\r\n");
            //writer.writeNext(CSVcursor.getColumnNames()); //Write the column headings first before the looping starts
            String [] headings = ("Order Id,Item ID,Item Name,Item Price,Item Count,Item Total,Paid Amount,VOID Order,Payment Method,Order Signature,Member/Authorization,Tab Number,Order Time").split(",");
            writer.writeNext(headings);

            for(CSVcursor.moveToFirst(); !CSVcursor.isAfterLast(); CSVcursor.moveToNext()) //Loop through all results (use row count of table)
            {
                String[] entries = (CSVcursor.getInt(CSVcursor.getColumnIndex("orderId"))+ ","
                        +CSVcursor.getInt(CSVcursor.getColumnIndex("itemId"))+ ","
                        +CSVcursor.getString(CSVcursor.getColumnIndex("itemName"))+ ","
                        +CSVcursor.getString(CSVcursor.getColumnIndex("itemPrice")) + ","
                        +CSVcursor.getInt(CSVcursor.getColumnIndex("itemCount"))+ ","
                        +CSVcursor.getString(CSVcursor.getColumnIndex("itemTotal"))+ ","
                        +CSVcursor.getString(CSVcursor.getColumnIndex("orderPaid"))+ ","
                        +CSVcursor.getInt(CSVcursor.getColumnIndex("orderVoid"))+ ","
                        +CSVcursor.getString(CSVcursor.getColumnIndex("orderType"))+ ","
                        +CSVcursor.getBlob(CSVcursor.getColumnIndex("orderSignature"))+ ","
                        +CSVcursor.getString(CSVcursor.getColumnIndex("referenceId"))+ ","
                        +CSVcursor.getInt(CSVcursor.getColumnIndex("orderTab"))+ ","
                        +CSVcursor.getString(CSVcursor.getColumnIndex("orderTime"))).split(","); //Split the string by the delimiter
                writer.writeNext(entries); //Write current row of DB to file
                writer.flush(); //Flush the stream
            }
            writer.close();
```

The file is getting written to successfully, but when I view the .csv file, the column that is saving the blob data looks like this.

B@2342342
B@2123982
B@3952929

It looks like I'm just saving the signature or some other attribute of the file rather than the file itself.

Do I need to stream the blob by bit/buffer into the csv file?

Comment: A more typical solution would be to save the image as a separate file. Otherwise, you will need to decide how to turn the `byte[]` from your BLOB column into some string representation, then put the string into your CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just echoing @CommonsWare.  The right thing to do is save the blob to the disk as am image.  That way it can be easily retrieved for embedding into a file if needed.  I still save my images to the db as blobs and just display them in a view.  If you want to put these files into a csv, I would consider another type like pdf.